# Only import data within a certain date from SQL into Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

Using Excel 2013, I have connected to a SQL database in our CRM program. I am running Activity reports, and I really only need data from the last 90 days. Is there a way I can limit the amount of SQL records that import into my Excel sheet to those within the last 90 days? I'm using this data for an auto-refreshing dashboard, and it takes 2-3 minutes per refresh because there are over 71,000 lines.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only if the SQL records contain a date field.

Change your query to add a restrictive clause on that date :

```
select your_data 
from your_tables 
where
your_existing_conditions 
and date_field >= getdate() - 90
;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the SQL data does have a date field. When you say to change the query, is this something that needs to be done within SQL? I didn't build a query in Excel, I just when through the database connection. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: I'm not expert with Excel. In 2007 version (hope it's the same with 2013), you can change this in the properties of the connection (data=>connections=>your connection=>properties=>tab "definition"). Type of command : use "SQL" instead of "table" and write the request in the text field.

Answer (score 1):

When you make the connection to your data source, just before you select where you want the data to show up in the Import Data dialog box, hit the Properties button.

[image]

Go to the Definition tab and change Command Type from Table to SQL.  Then you can enter your SQL query (assuming you have correct permissions) where you filter your results.

If you don't have permissions, you would need to have your DB team create a view that you pull in instead of a table that does the filtering for you.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Excel 2013 are you using? If it is a version that has PowerPivot included, I suggest you use that to connect to the database as it is much better at handling large numbers of rows, you won't have to worry about limiting the rows for a long time to come.

Alternatively, in the data menu, go to 'From Other Sources' and select 'From Microsoft Query' That will give you options for putting conditions on the data you take in. If you're not familiar with SQL, then this will take care of the underlying WHERE condition for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! Based on the feedback here, I solved my issue by writing my first-ever SQL query (don't laugh)! By going to the Definition tab in Connection Properties and changing the Command type to SQL, I wrote a very simple code adding the date range. Thanks again.